# Отключение аппаратных кнопок

Tags: android

Как отключить аппаратные кнопки "*меню*" и "*назад*" в **activity**?

Comment: кнопки у вас отключить не получится. Но можете, например, переопределить метод `onBackPressed()`, и оставить его пустым, чтобы кнопка "назад" продолжала работать, но по нажатию на нее ничего не происходило. И просто убрать меню, чтобы оно не показывалось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переопределить поведение кнопки "назад" можно через метод `onBackPressed()` следующим образом:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // super.onBackPressed();
    // ваш код
}
```

Переопределить поведение кнопки "меню" можно следующими методами:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // ваш код
        //return true;
    }
    //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // ваш код
        //return true;
    }
    //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Если вам нужно именно "отключить" эти кнопки, оставьте методы пустыми. 
**Однако лучше не делайте этого, если у вас нет серьёзных причин это делать**. Переопределение поведения по умолчанию для кнопки назад (да и других аппаратных кнопок) - моветон. Вот что говорит на этот счёт [документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html?hl=ru):

> Внимание! В большинстве приложений не следует прерывать поведение
>   операций и задач по умолчанию. Если вы обнаружили, что вашей операции
>   необходимо изменить поведение по умолчанию, будьте внимательны и
>   протестируйте удобство работы с операцией во время запуска и при
>   обратной навигации к ней из других операций и задач с помощью кнопки
>   Назад. Обязательно протестируйте поведение навигации, которое может
>   противоречить поведению, ожидаемому пользователем.

Comment: А где я могу взять keyCode?

Comment: @GuardFromUA, обновила ответ: `keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU`

Comment: а как мне вызвать этот метод в onCreate? Что только не пробовал - подчеркивает...

Comment: @GuardFromUA, вы не можете вызвать эти методы в onCreate. Эти методы должны быть вызваны в вашей Activity рядом с onCreate, но не в нём.

Comment: Странно, ***onBackPressed()*** заработал только после вызова... Но переопределен он был не в OnCreate... Override же не сработает, если  это дело делать в OnCreate

Comment: @GuardFromUA, я уже писала выше в комментариях - эти методы не нужно вызывать внутри метода onCreate!

Comment: @GuardFromUA, вот вам простейший пример, как должны располагаться эти методы: http://android-coding.blogspot.com.by/2011/10/handle-back-key-by-overriding.html